# Some misunderstanding about this word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript block:

```
function List() {
 List.makeNode = function() {
  return {data: null, next: null};
 };

 this.start = null;
 this.end = null;

 this.add = function(data) {
  //some code
  this.end.data = data;
 };
}
```

My question is about the meaning of word **this** in those rows:

```
 this.start = null;
 this.add = function(data)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `this` points the instance of the object. The line `this.start` sets the datamember `start` to `null` for the instance.

Comment: [MDN this Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: [Here's an great source](http://bit.ly/1qKju71) about the this keyword

Answer (score 1):

`this` points to the instance of the object. So if you were to do this:

```
var potato = new List();
```

potato would have (pretty much) properties assigned to it, called `start` and `end`. You would access them like this:

```
potato.start /* equals null, because the 
             function constructor set it to null 
             using the this keyword,
             this.start = null;
             */
```

You can try it yourself. Start your console (Ctrl+shift+j) and type in this:

```
function Foo(){
  this.length = 'bar';
  this.stuff = 'buzz';
}
```

Now try assigning it to a variable:

```
var foo = new Foo;
```

and accessing those properties.

```
foo.length
// returns 'bar'

foo.stuff
//returns 'buzz'
```

If you changed these:

```
foo.length = 'I have no length';
```

It would only apply to that instance, so if you were to do:

```
var foo2 = new Foo();

foo2.length
//still returns 'bar'

foo.length
// still 'I have no length'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.start = null;
```

initializes the property start on an instance of the List() class when you use it as a constructor. It will allow you to append additional properties or methods to List.start if you want to, as was done for List.end with List.end.data.

so

```
this.start = null;
```

allows you to say,

```
this.start.newProperty = "new";
```

If you didn't initialize this.start, most browsers would throw an error and most likely halt your program when you tried to create the new property.

```
this.add = function(data) {}
```

Creates a method for the List class, so that when you create an instance of List, you can all it like List.add()

Usage:

```
var myList = new List(); // Create a new instance of the List() class.

myList.add("my data"); // Store "my data" in myList.end.data via the add() method

alert(myList.end.data); // Would show "my data" in an alert box.
```

Hope this clarifies things a little bit.